# C# What exception should be thrown when number out of range

Tags: c#, exception

I have a simple C# method that generates a number. If the system tries to generate a number out of the range that has been defined, I'd like to throw an exception but there are so many, I'm not sure what exception to throw?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.systemexception.aspx

An example would be a method that returns the next number available, but should not be greater than 100.  If the system tries to generate a number (i.e. 101) then I want to throw an exception.

Comment: when in doubt I use FileNotFoundException

Comment: Additionally, is there a general rule when you should throw an exception vs handling it in code?  For example I could have just returned a message saying that the number couldn't be generated.

Comment: @TravisK That's up to you. Personally, I handle the majority of errors. However, there are instances that I throw exceptions when certain senarios should never happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` - The exception that is thrown when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method. (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The [OverflowException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception?view=net-5.0) seems to do what you're looking for:

> OverflowException, which is thrown when the result of an operation is
> outside the bounds of the target data type. That is, it is less than a
> number's MinValue property or greater than its MaxValue property. For
> example, attempting to assign 200 + 200 to a Byte value throws an
> OverflowException exception, since 400 greater than 256, the upper
> bound of the Byte data type.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arithmeticexception?view=net-5.0